# Problems using nose in a virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, nose, nosetests

I am unable to use nose (nosetests) in a virtualenv project - it can't seem to find the packages installed in the virtualenv environment.

The odd thing is that i can set

```
test_suite = 'nose.collector'
```

in setup.py and run the tests just fine as

```
python setup.py test
```

but when running nosetests straight, there are all sorts of import errors.

I've tried it with both a system-wide installation of nose and a virtualenv nose package and no luck.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!!

Comment: On a related note, nose works fine "out of the box" on a different computer... so there's something wonky with the system I was having problems on.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Are you able to run `myenv/bin/python /usr/bin/nosetests`? That should run Nose using the virtual environment's library set.

Comment: If using with scripts that other developers will use, you can do `python \`which nosetests\``

Comment: Try this
alias nosetests='/usr/bin/env python $(which nosetests)'

Answer (score 63):

You need to have a copy of nose installed in the virtual environment. In order to force installation of nose into the virtualenv, even though it is already installed in the global site-packages, run `pip install` with the `-I` flag:

```
(env1)$ pip install nose -I
```

From then on you can just run `nosetests` as usual.

Comment: It seems that one might have to refresh the virtualenv. Namely, `which nosetests` should point to an executable inside of the virtualenv.

Comment: +1 This is what worked for me. Also, as Ceasar points out, I also had to refresh the virtualenv by running `deactivate` and then reactivating.

Comment: After you use this command, then `deactivate`, then `workon ENV`, it seems you can then use ``python `which nosetests` ``.

Comment: When `which nosetests` does not correctly point to the venv, check if you have installed `nose` or `nose2`, and note that `nose2` does not use the `nosetests` executable (but uses `nose2` instead). D-oh!

Answer (score 12):

In the same situation I needed to reload the `virtualenv` for the path to be correctly updated:

```
deactivate
env/bin/activate
```

Comment: This is the one that did it for me. Any idea why you need to re-activate after installing nose (or nose2, in my case)?

Comment: @hansmosh, cannot test right now, it would be useful to check all the paths

Comment: I had nose installed globally so the nosetests executable didn't resolve properly. the following worked:
python `which nosetests` 

but this is the actual solution for me.

Answer (score 9):

I got a similar problem. The following workaround helped:

```
python `which nosetests`
```

(instead of just `nosestests`)

Answer (score 8):

Here's what works for me:

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages env1
$ cd env1
$ source bin/activate            # makes "env1" environment active,
                                 # you will notice that the command prompt
                                 # now has the environment name in it.

(env1)$ easy_install nose        # install nose package into "env1"
```

I created a really basic package `slither` that had, in its `setup.py`, same `test_suite` attribute as you mentioned above. Then I placed the package source under `env1/src`.

If you looked inside `env1/src`, you'd see:

```
slither/setup.py
slither/slither/__init__.py
slither/slither/impl.py          # has some very silly code to be tested
slither/slither/tests.py         # has test-cases
```

I can run the tests using `test` subcommand:

```
(env1)$ pushd src/slither
(env1)$ python setup.py test
# ... output elided ...
test_ctor (slither.tests.SnakeTests) ... ok
test_division_by_zero (slither.tests.SnakeTests) ... ok
Ran 2 tests in 0.009s
OK
(env1)$ popd
```

Or, I can run the same tests with `nosetests`:

```
(env1)$ pushd src
(env1)$ nosetests slither/
..
Ran 2 tests in 0.007s
OK
(env1)$ popd
```

Also note that `nosetests` can be picky about executables. You can pass `--exe` if you want it to discover tests in python modules that are executable.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, try installing nose in your venv, and/or run `nosetests-2.7`. I believe @andrea-zonca's answer has the same effect if your venv python is 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a recent change, but for me, when I installed nosetests through pip, there was a nosetests executable installed in `.virtualenvs/<env>/bin`, which (unsurprisingly) operates correctly with the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a `nosetests` that is installed somewhere else in your `PATH` with higher priority than the one installed in your virtualenv. A quick way to give the `nose` module and associated `nosetests` script installed in your current virtualenv top priority is to edit your `PATH`:

```
export PATH=/path/to/current/virtualenv/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party.

*Regardless, if you see this in the year 2021...*
These issues, for me, surrounding nose, nose-cov and pinocchio were resolved by updating my Virtual Envs to at least Python 3.8.2..