# ImportError: No module named flask_material

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, nose

I am running python2.7 and there is this problem I am facing on my server when I run `nosetests -v` to run unit tests against my python+flask application. This app is running on a VE (virtual environment) and I have installed the `flask-material` design package from GitHub here: https://github.com/HellerCommaA/flask-materialize.

Each time I run `nosetests -v` to test the application, I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named flask_material
```

but I have imported the module as describe in the docs and I have tried google searching this error but did find a hit. I don't know what I am missing or what I am doing wrong, any help please?

Comment: Looks like your virtual environment is not active.

Comment: Check your installed modules using command: `pip freeze`

Comment: @SohaibFarooqi, yes flask-material is there. Its installed.

Comment: @KlausD, What do you mean by its not active? I just created the VE recently.

Comment: Creating a virtual environment isn't enough. You need to activate it as well. Typically this will resemble `source bin/activate`  If you have activated it, are you certain that nose is installed in the environment?

Comment: @dirn, I am in the environment, Its active and I am using it and `nose` is installed on it. That is why I posted the question, I don't get the point for error in importing a package when its installed and I am on the VE.

Comment: @d3r1ck check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604699/how-to-activate-virtualenv) on activating a virtualenv. Once you're in the activated venv, use `pip` to check the installed packages on the venv.

Comment: @sytech, I have done all that. I am in an activated env and I have checked the installed packages.

Comment: Is nose installed to that virtualenv? [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864956/problems-using-nose-in-a-virtualenv) describes a few different possible culprits and solutions.

Comment: @sytech, yes. Nose is installed.